# Raspberrypi 21.10 Server static IP but boots with 2 IP (one from DHCP?)

Tags: raspberrypi, netplan, ip

Set up pi with a static IP (10.0.0.180/24) following https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi
Raspberrypi4 -4 with 8g

At boot it displays

```
eth0 IP 10.0.0.180
eth0 IP 10.0.0.55
```

10.0.0.55 seems to be from my router dhcp.
Gateway & Nameserver are as I setup in network-config file.
In the tutorial, it suggest I have to replace "dhcp4 : true"
Do I have to set dhcp4 : false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment above *"There is also a "dhcp4 : true" in the netplan file that links the hardware to eth0"* is the problem.
I guess it should not be in that file at all (ever?).
It should only be part of the network-config, since the cloud-init causes netplan to write a new YAML file. Both YAML files are read and combined so netplan subsequently uses the static address & then does a DHCP as well

Answer (score 0):

```
In the tutorial, it suggest I have to replace "dhcp4 : true" 
Do I have to set dhcp4 : false?
```

If you do not want a DHCP address from the router, then remove the reference to DHCP altogether. You can see an example template here:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml
```

Of course, susbstitute your exact details. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Did a little more digging. There is also a "dhcp4 : true" in the netplan file that links the hardware to eth0. on boot the cloud-init rewrites the network-config file to a yaml file in the /etc/netplan directory.